# Error: no provisioning profile matches xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode-command-line-tools

[BuilSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za2eJ.png)[REFERENCE IMAGE1[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQNWN.png)I'm creating an script to automate ios build to generate .ipa ... Below is my script,

```
# xcodebuild -workspace "project.xcworkspace" -scheme "Schemename" clean

# xcodebuild -workspace "project.xcworkspace" -scheme "Schemename" build

# xcodebuild archive -workspace "project.xcworkspace" -scheme "schemename" -archivePath "project.xcworkspace.xcarchive"

# xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "project.xcworkspace.xcarchive" -exportPath "project.xcworkspace" -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "Digi Form Development": *"
```

while executing above script getting an error of,

> --- xcodebuild: WARNING: -exportArchive without -exportOptionsPlist is deprecated error: no provisioning profile matches 'Digi Form
>   Development: *'
>   ** EXPORT FAILED **

Since I'm new to this ios build deployment using xcode cli kindly help me on to correct my problems,

Comment: It says that your provisioning profile is wrong. Please check whether `Digi Form Development` is the correct provisioning profile or not.

Comment: @KrishnaCA : Thanks the provisioning profile is exist on developer.apple.com under my account. Not sure with the exact problem kindly help.

Comment: Are you using the same bundle identifier on Xcode which you are using to create your provisioning Profile. Both are same?

Comment: @MandeepSingh : Yes I'm using the same bundle identifier and both are same.

Comment: Have you add your account to Xcode and add your team on Build settings before where we select the provisioning profile?

Comment: Untick the Automatically manage signing and select your provisioning profile in general(Tab) again. Then run your command.

Comment: From the image, we can see that your provisioning profile is not set properly

Comment: Thanks @MandeepSingh Okay I will unchecked the automatically manage option and do check.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaCA

Comment: Facing an same issue.@MandeepSingh @KrishnaCA

Comment: Now I changed the profile name to "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: * " after changed getting an different error, --- xcodebuild: WARNING: -exportArchive without -exportOptionsPlist is deprecated
error: Code signing operation failed
** EXPORT FAILED **

Comment: Please show images of your Build settings -> Code signing so that we can check whether you're setting it correctly

Comment: @KrishnaCA I'm doing it from cli. When I build and archive from xcode gui I didn't face such issue...it's only when I doing it from CLI

Comment: @KrishnaCA : Attached the build settings please verify.

Comment: Verified. As I told you, your build settings are incorrect. 1) Change the provisioning profile from automatic to your `iOS Team Provisioning Profile` 2) Change the code signing from `Don't code sign` to valid setting. Click on it to get more options and choose the valid code signing option. It will be like `iOS Distribution` or something similar

Comment: @KrishnaCA : Can you correct if any mistake here, # xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "project.xcworkspace.xcarchive" -exportPath "project.xcworkspace" -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "Digi Form Development" -alltargets -parallelizeTargets -configuration Debug CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: sudhakaran.rajendran@---.com (5PZNHKLMM)" also I have multiple code-signin certificate is that cause any conflicts?

Comment: what about Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY? you're supposed to set it for both Release and Debug I believe. Is it working now?

Comment: @KrishnaCA: Yep...I done for both release and debug but no luck still get the same issue.

Comment: @KrishnaCA : Any further try out or I miss out something as said I have multiple certificates is that causing any conflicts?

Comment: Still getting the same issue as in the question?

Comment: @KrishnaCA: yes still has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a exportOptions.plist file, then add the command line flag as so:

```
-exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

The export options plist should look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>compileBitcode</key>
  <false/>
  <key>method</key>
  <string>ad-hoc</string>
  <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
  <dict>
    <key>my.bundle.idenifier</key>
    <string>My Provisioning Profile Name</string>
  </dict>
  <key>signingCertificate</key>
  <string>iPhone Distribution</string>
  <key>signingStyle</key>
  <string>manual</string>
  <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
  <true/>
  <key>teamID</key>
  <string>YOURTEAMID</string>
  <key>thinning</key>
  <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note that signing style can be manual or automatic.  If you are explicitly setting the provisioning profile, which I tend to do, use manual and specify the provisioning profile name explicitly.  If automatic, Xcode will try to automatically find a matching profile.

For the method field, the options are: development, ad-hoc, distribution and enterprise.

Here is a link with a more general description on this feature: http://devcenter.bitrise.io/tips-and-tricks/xcodebuild-export-options/